# Jython, how to place image at the center of another image

Tags: image, jython, pixel, jes

I need some help with Jython, I am supposed to place an image into another image so it will looked [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOsUV.png)

However, with my current code, my result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD7D5.png)

Could someone please help me?

Thanks.

```
def copyPicture(pict):
  tpict = makeEmptyPicture(getWidth(pict)*2, getHeight(pict)*2)
  for x in range(0,getWidth(pict)):
    for y in range(0,getHeight(pict)):
      srcPix=getPixel(pict, x,y)
      tgtPix=getPixel(tpict,x,y)
      setColor(tgtPix, getColor(srcPix))
  for x in range(0,getWidth(pict)):
    for y in range(0,getHeight(pict)):
      srcPix=getPixel(pict,getWidth(pict)-x-1,y)
      tgtPix=getPixel(tpict,x+getWidth(pict),y)
      setColor(tgtPix, getColor(srcPix))
  for x in range(0,getWidth(tpict)):
    for y in range(0,getHeight(tpict)/2):
      srcPix=getPixel(tpict,x,y)
      tgtPix=getPixel(tpict,x,getHeight(pict)+getHeight(pict)-y-1)
      setColor(tgtPix,getColor(srcPix))
  x1=getWidth(tpict)/2    
  for x in range(0,getWidth(pict),2):
    y1=getHeight(tpict)/2
    for y in range(0,getHeight(pict),2):
      srcPix=getPixel(pict,x,y)
      tgtPix=getPixelAt(tpict,x1,y1)
      setColor(tgtPix, getColor(srcPix))
      y1=y1+1
    x1=x1+1
  repaint(tpict)
```

Comment: You need to set `x1=getWidth(tpict)/2 - getWidth(pict),2)/2` and likewise for `y1` - I think!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the result is different :/